# Specify SSL for Heroku external MySQL database connection

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, heroku

I'm running a Rails 3.2 app on the Cedar stack at Heroku.

I'm using Amazon RDS for my MySQL database, and I have the proper DATABASE_URL setup in the Heroku config vars.

How do I get Heroku to use SSL in its connection to Amazon RDS?

Normally this would be specified as a value in database.yml, but since Heroku generates database.yml for us, I'm not sure how to control this setting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the injected database.yml (see bottom of http://neilmiddleton.com/sharing-databases-between-heroku-applications/) you can pass in extra configuration as part of the db URL as query params.

In theory, this should let you configure it how you want although I've not tried it.

Comment: Thanks Neil. That worked great!  More specifically, my Heroku config DATABASE_URL looks something like: mysql2://username:password@hostname/databasename?sslca=/path/to/ca.pem

Answer (score 17):

You can specify [some mysql2 SSL params](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#ssl-options) through the `DATABASE_URL` config. They will get added as items to the dynamic `database.yml` that is generated during the Heroku build process, and so they'll be passed when mysql2 connections are created.

The only param you need to pass for this to work is `sslca` (not to be confused with `sslcapath`).

**1. Download the [Amazon RDS CA certificate](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport) and bundle it with your app.**

(Edit) Amazon will be [rotating this certificate](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html#UsingWithRDS.SSL.Rotation) in March 2015. You'll need the new file from that page instead of this one.

`curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem > ./config/amazon-rds-ca-cert.pem`

**2. Add the file to git, and redeploy to Heroku.**

**3. Change `DATABASE_URL` to pass `sslca`:**

`heroku config:add DATABASE_URL="mysql2://username:password@hostname/dbname?sslca=config/amazon-rds-ca-cert.pem -a <app_id>`

The relative path there is important—see below.

That's it! Now that you have SSL working, you may want to enforce that all connections with that user only allow SSL:

```
GRANT USAGE ON dbname.* TO 'username'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;
```

---

*Troubleshooting*

Make sure to pass a relative path to `sslca`! Otherwise, `rake assets:precompile` may break with an SSL error. If you receive an error like:

```
SSL connection error: ASN: bad other signature confirmation
```

or even just:

```
SSL connection error
```

...then there is likely something wrong with how the CA cert file is referenced.

Comment: under step 3: what is the -a <app_id> suppose to be? is the name of the heroku app?

Comment: If you only have one app -a {app_id} can often be skipped. Use ```heroku apps``` in the terminal to see what apps belong to the logged in user.

Comment: Additionally I had to add the mysql port to our security group. The source is: 0.0.0.0/0 and port range is: 3306

Comment: @djburdick - Be careful! Allowing a source of 0.0.0.0/0 (or anything /0) is opening up your database firewall to the world. Unfortunately that is Heroku's current recommendation, but you should be aware that's what you are doing.

Comment: @fotinakis agree! Thanks for calling this out. I actually put in a request to their support about this :). Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945465/heroku-with-amazon-rds-security/22946021?noredirect=1#22946021