# Heroku with amazon RDS security

Tags: mysql, heroku, amazon-web-services

I've setup our heroku app with an amazon RDS instance.

I followed the guide here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon_rds

This guide basically says to require SSL with the connection and then to input your RDS credentials.

This doesn't seem very secure to me. If someone has my db url, user and password then they can login from anywhere, correct? The SSL is nice to prevent sniffing of this info, but I'd like to lock it down further, to a machine, IP address or SSH.

I previously setup RDS DB instances where access was locked down to only specific IPs, but heroku no longer recommends this for whatever reason.

So the questions are:

- Are my assumptions correct here?
- How can I lock this down further?
- Why doesn't heroku recommend locking it down to IP (or at least IP range)

I'll run this by heroku support as well and post an update, but wanted to get thoughts from the community.

Answer (score 1):

Previously, Heroku recommended locking down access by referencing the Heroku AWS account ID. [That approach is no longer recommended](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/353). The Heroku changelog entry lists the reasons, reproducing here for completeness:

- Cross-security grants don't work with [AWS VPC](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) (which is now the default on AWS)
- It's not safe because it grants access to all apps running on Heroku, not just yours
- Doesn't work across AWS regions
- Heroku may in the future run apps in a VPC or in a different region or use a different AWS account

We know that not all customers are happy with this level of access granularity, and we're continuously evaluating whether this is the optimal setup.

Comment: Any ideas on how to lock this down more? Is there any way we can reserve an IP address for instance? Or at least an IP range?

Comment: @djburdick there's currently no way to lock that down further, I'm afraid. You app dynos can be deployed on any of the Heroku runtime instances, and we don't publish the IPs of those. Also, it would still leave your database open to attack from any other app that happens to be running on Heroku, sharing an IP with your app's dynos.